# Opacity in CSS to not affect the div

Tags: html, css

I have a code that put a background image in a div but when I use opacity all the div is affected even the text inside it here is my code;

```
  .banner_area .banner_inner {
    opacity: .5;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 395px;
    background: url(../img/breadcrumb/checkout-bg.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1; }
```

I tried `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);` but my image is not displaying

also I've tried     `background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url(../img/breadcrumb/checkout-bg.jpg);` but its not working

Comment: Can you post the HTML? Right now, you're trying to select a *child* of `.banner_area` with the class of `banner_inner`. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set an opacity only to the background image of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241341/can-i-set-an-opacity-only-to-the-background-image-of-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, as can't see the htmlt but first I'd add the overlay dynamically with the `::before` pseudoelement and then will fix the z-index

```
.banner_area:before {
  opacity: .5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 395px;
  background: url(../img/breadcrumb/checkout-bg.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1; 
}
```

Then would put the content and should not be opaque

Comment: Before works thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

I have created one [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voxgtr2m/1/) . 
Is this something you are looking for?

```
 .banner_area .banner_inner {
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 395px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492__480.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: bottom;
  background-position: center;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```