# How can I make the background of a div inside a react component transparent?

Tags: css, reactjs

setting the following

```
const compStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}
```

or RGBA does not work, just makes it white.

Comment: Did you check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565384/how-to-make-the-background-div-only-transparent-using-css

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with the position. Setting

`position: absolute`

worked.