# Semi-transparent <Select> element in HTML

Tags: html, css, transparency

I'm looking for a way to make semi-transparent  form elements in HTML.

I know that CSS3 has the lovely background-color:rgba(r,g,b,a) option, and equally using a semi-transparent .png as a background image usually works, however I can't get it to work for the  element.

I'm mainly targeting modern browsers (IE9 and updated versions of FF/Chrome/Safari), and I'm not too fussed for the solution to be backwards-compatible (degrading to a solid color is fine). Even a solution that works in some of these would be acceptable, especially if it's expected that future versions of the other browsers will support it (I'm looking at you IE!).

Comment: as I faced these scenarios already, I have found the <select>, checkbox and radio button styles cannot be done easily as we wish even if we use CSS3(experts if I am wrong please correct me). As a result I have created jQuery plugins to handle these stuffs and using it for web developments..

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/23SMa/

Comment: @irrelephant I do not think it is a perfect solution because the text available inside select element (not in dropdown) is also not clearly visible enough.. just a suggestion friend...

Comment: Indeed that does the job reasonably well, thanks for that!
edit: Faizul is correct, it does fade out the text too, still it's better than nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't go for the `background-color:rgba`, use `opacity:x` instead. IE9, Chrome, FF, Opera and Safari use this for transparency.
For example:

```
<select style="opacity:0.5;">
```

Opacity takes values between 0 (full transparent) and 1.

Although you're mainly targeting modern browsers, for IE8 and earlier you have to use `filter:alpha(opacity=50)` (with respect to the above example; opacity here accepts values between 0 and 100).

So in conclusion

```
<select style="opacity:0.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50);">
```

gives you a semi-transparent select control supported by modern browsers plus IE8 and earlier.

With this technique, the selects childs options will also gain the specified opacity, so the text of the option-tags will be faded out, too.
Mikkel Fausing found out that using `background-color:rgba(r,g,b,a)` in combination with `-webkit-appearance: none;` doesn't fade the text, but - if applied to a select - it removes the little arrow indicating that this control is a dropdownbox. For example:

```
<select style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -webkit-appearance:none;">
```

Comment: Then [stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text) may help you.

Comment: I *think* I found a solution that works in IE9, FF and Chrome (not tested on Safari or Opera).

The tricks seems to be using -webkit-appearance:none. I'm not quite sure if there's issues with that though, example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikkelpf/3m3vT/

Comment: -webkit-appearance:none will remove your arrow from the select dropdown.. isn't it?.. I already tried almost all the solution by taking more than 3 days and it make to learn a lot about select, checkbox and radio..

Comment: You're right, it removes the arrow as well. However, that's acceptable to me in the current scenario - even if it's generally a bad idea to do so.

Comment: @BastiM: Setting the Opacity will fade out the text too, and setting the <Option> parts to be of a higher Opacity level doesn't work - updated the jsfiddle to use both "solutions": http://jsfiddle.net/mikkelpf/3m3vT/2/

Comment: @MikkelFausing whatever you do you can't modify the select as your wish and its dropdown(options). I could not share my own plugin which I used is in jsFiddle (frankly do not know the reason).. if any ways exists let me know, I will send that plugin to you...

Comment: For completeness I just added the -webkit-appearance:none; solution to the answer.

Comment: @BastiM I accepted your answer, because I believe the information in there is as close as it's possible to get at this point in time, unless you do what Faizul Hasan did and write your own UI elements (that's sidestepping the issue rather than solving it - though it's probably a good way to do it). I'm not sure what the "normal" way to do things is around here, being new, but I believe accepting an answer that's close is better than leaving it with no answer, as it may be "good enough" for certain use cases (it's acceptable for my current project).