# Making text background transparent but not text itself

Tags: html, css, text, opacity

So I am having a problem. I have looked around and looked around but no luck. I would like to make the background of my body transparent but leave the text non transparent. As it is right now I keep making both the same opacity. Here is my code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #42413C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}

/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    opacity:1;
}
a img { 
    border: none;
}
a:link {
    color: #42413C;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
    color: #6E6C64;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    padding:20px;
    width:710px;
    position:relative;
    background:#CCC;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.fltrt {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { 
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
.header {
    top:0%;
    width: 750px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
.navbar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 750px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
#bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: -1;
}
div {
display: block;
}
```

Here is my website (click the link dont type "tccraft.net" in your url it will take you to a facebook page): http://tccraft.net/index.php
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent background, but not the content (text & images) inside it, in CSS only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on)

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Don't use `opacity` for this, set the background to an RGBA-value instead to only make the background semi-transparent. In your case it would be like this.

```
.content {
    padding:20px;
    width:710px;
    position:relative;
    background: rgb(204, 204, 204); /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
}
```

See http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ for more info and samples of rgba-values in css.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this with a background image?

Comment: For background images, just use a PNG or WEBP with an alpha channel as your image.

Answer (score 28):

For a fully transparent background use:

```
background: transparent;
```

Otherwise for a semi-transparent color fill use:

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); // or hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5)
```

where the values are:

```
background: rgba(red,green,blue,opacity); // or hsla(hue, saturation, lightness, opacity)
```

You can also use rgba values for gradient backgrounds.

To get transparency on an image background simply reduce the opacity of the image in an image editor of you choice beforehand.

Comment: Is there a link to more info about `background: transparent;`? I can't get it to work or find the docs for it.

Answer (score 2):

`opacity` will make both text and background transparent. Use a semi-transparent background-color instead, by using a `rgba()` value for example. Works on IE8+

Answer (score 0):

If you use RGBA for modern browsers you don't need let older IEs use only the non-transparent version of the given color with RGB.

If you don't stick to CSS-only solutions, give [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) a try. With this syntax you can see exactly the same result in older IEs that you see in modern browsers:

```
div {
    -pie-background: rgba(223,231,233,0.8);
    behavior: url(../PIE.htc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the background of your body transparent please try this style, it worked for me, add "ad" at the end of your desired color code

```
background-color: #42413Cad !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add Hex color code for transparency

background-color: #42413C+hexcode

https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4
It would be somethin like this:

```
background-color: #42413C2E
```

It is equal to that color + 18% alpha

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with z-index.

The watermark class (you can use an example from [#19531361](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531361)) does the job. All input tags are non transparent, but they sit "behind" the watermark. To make them active, use following css modifications (inputs are then "on top").

```
input {
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}

.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 25%;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I modified my answer. Please let me know, if it seems more clear now.

Answer (score -3):

```
box-shadow: inset 1px 2000px rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.54);
```