# transparent background for horizontal ticks of column chart

Tags: javascript, html, data-visualization, google-visualization

I have a column chart. I set the text position of the hAxis to in using `'textPosition': 'in'`.

They shown like [image]

Currently text background is white. I want to make it transparent. How can I ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS text background transparent but text not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449280/html-css-text-background-transparent-but-text-not)

Answer (score 1):

there are no options to change the text stroke color,
but you can change manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event.

you may need to inspect the `text` elements to find an attribute you can use to differentiate the axis labels from other chart labels.

here, the `'text-anchor'` attribute is used,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y2');
  data.addRows([
    [2010, 1000, 100, 1200],
    [2020, 1000, 100, 1200],
    [2030, 1000, 100, 1200]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // find labels, remove stroke
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') {
        label.setAttribute('stroke', 'none');
        label.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0');
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      format: '0000',
      textPosition: 'in'
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```