# How to make only the div color transparent?

Tags: html, colors, opacity

Css:

```
  #container
     {
     position:relative;
     left: 28%;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
     background: black;
     opacity:0.7;
     }
```

Html:

```
 <div id="container">
  Here are texts,images,etc
 </div>
```

I cant think of a way to make transparent just the div color without affecting the content of #container.Someone know one?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/891366/1715716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-color: rgba(150,150,150,Val between 0 and 1);
```

`RGBA` stands for `red green blue alpha`. The value of `alpha` is used to determine the intensity of the transparency. `0` being fully transparent and `1` being fully opaque.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2huc/)**

Comment: yea this is good thank you.Just one problem the color is gray not black....what should i modify?

Comment: You have to modify the rgb value. Try 120,120,120 for gray shade.

Comment: well is still gray...i want a black transparent

Comment: @Lebada For black try rgba(0,0,0,0.4)