# Getting transparency from an upper element

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I have got a background of light blue, then on top of that I have a white transparent rectangle.  Then all in there I have a div where my actual information is going to be, laid out like this

```
<div id = "transparent"> 

<div id = "yourinfo">

<div id = "profileinfo">
    <span id = "yourname"> Name </span>
    <br>
    <span> View </span>

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

However when I try and give a background colour to my main page above the transparent rectangle, this element is also transparent, how do I remove this transparency and get this element to appear as if on top of the transparent rectangle?

Here is my css for these elements

```
div#transparent{
    margin: 40px 40px auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    height: 620px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity:.3;
    padding: 20px;
}

div#yourinfo{
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: semi-transparent background, but not text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS opacity applies to children elements. To accomplish what you wish you will have to use the `rgba` (RGB plus Alpha/Transparency channel) on your `background-color` declaration.

Such as:

```
#transparent {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3)
}
```

Be aware that this approach does not work with IE8<, so you might have to look for a workaround. Either you use a transparent `.png` (like in the olden days) or you use some conditional stylesheet and the [Microsoft Internet Explorer proprietary syntax](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/).

Also, obviously, this approach will only work if you don't want `#transparent` to have semi-transparent text; all text will be 100% opaque in that `div`. Accordingly, you can use the same CSS3 syntax on the text color.