# Submenu with opacity

Tags: css

My submenu text is with opacity... i need text black but he have opacity with cames from menu i thing.

Submenu code,

```
.fancyNav{
/* Affects the UL element */
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
z-index:999;
}
.fancyNav li{
/* Specifying a fallback color and we define CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */

 background: #CCC;
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=10);
   opacity:.7;

border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);

/* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */



position:relative;

float: left;
list-style: none;
}

.fancyNav li:after{
    content:'.';
text-indent:-9999px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0; 
opacity:0;
z-index:1;
/* Gradients! */

background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(168,168,168,0)), to(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)));

background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,1));

background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));

/* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */

box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

/* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */

-moz-transition:0.25s all;
-webkit-transition:0.25s all;
-o-transition:0.25s all;
transition:0.25s all;}

/* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */



.fancyNav li:first-child:after,
 .fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after{
box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

-moz-transition:0.25s all;
-webkit-transition:0.25s all;
-o-transition:0.25s all;
transition:0.25s all;}

 /* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */



.fancyNav li:first-child:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after{
box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

}

.fancyNav li:last-child{
}

/* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */

.fancyNav li:last-child:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:last-child:after{
box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
}
.fancyNav li:hover:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:after,
.fancyNav li:target:after{
/* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
opacity:1;
 }

.fancyNav:hover li.selected:after,
.fancyNav:hover li:target:after{
/* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
opacity:0;
}
.fancyNav li.selected:hover:after,
.fancyNav li:target:hover:after{
opacity:1 !important;

}
/* Styling the anchor elements */
.menudiv{
position:fixed;
z-index:999;
width:951px;
margin-left:-476px;
left:50%;
}
.menlog{
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;

}
.menlog2{
padding:12px 15px 15px;

}
.corrente{
   background-color:white;
padding:12px 15px 15px;
}
.corrente3{
}
.fancyNav li a{
color: #000000;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
z-index:2;
text-decoration:none !important;
white-space:nowrap;

}
.fancyNav a.homeIcon{
background:url('../img/home.png') no-repeat center center;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: -9999px;
}


nav{
display: block;
text-align: center;

}
a, a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
color:#54a6de;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
////

ul ul li{
float:none !important;
display: block;

}
ul ul{
display:none;
position:relative;    /* updated */
z-index:2;            /* updated */
background-color:#2f2f2f;

}
ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
border:0;
position:absolute;
background-color:#FFFFFF;


}
#quemsomos ul li {
border: none;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
```

How i ignore the opacity?

My html code

```
<nav>
<ul class="fancyNav">
    <li id="quemsomos" class="menlog"><a href="index.php"><img src="imgs/Logo.png"  width="37" height="45" /></a>
    </li>
    <li id="quemsomos"><a href="quemsomos.php?web=1"><font face="din" size="4">QUEM SOMOS</font></a>
        <!--start of sub menu-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link the zone 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">link2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">l for example</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--end of sub menu-->
<li><a href="arquitectura.php?web=10"><font face="din" size="4" color="#000000">ARQUITECTURA</font></a></li>
<li><a href="desenhointeriores.php?web=9"><font face="din" size="4">DESENHO DE INTERIORES</font></a></li>
<li></li>

</ul></li>

  </ul>
```

I dont know how i change this... my menu have opacity but the text dont have... so i dont know why submenu text have...

Comment: Where and how is the opacity defined? A JSFiddle would be of more help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: semi-transparent background, but not text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `background-color` of #ccc and an opacity of 0.7.

You need to change the background color so it has an alpha channel (or opacity value of it's own) then you can remove the opacity from the `li`.

So:

```
background: #ccc;
opacity:0.7;
```

will become

```
background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.7)
/* opacity:0.7 <-- delete this*/
```

Comment: Be sure to set a fallback color for browsers that don't support rgba! `background-color: #ccc; background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.7);`

Comment: Paulie i do what you said but now the background submenu dont have opacity but the text it is ok...

Comment: I'm unsure what that means but I'm sure you can tweak your sub-menus using the same principles.