# C# WebBrowser, setting opacity of div

Tags: c#, html, browser, opacity

I'm using a WebBrowser in my C# application to display my web page. I have a div that is set to semi-transparent using the standard rgba:

```
background-color:rgba(255,0,255,0.5);
```

It works fine in Firefox and my IE 10 but just doesn't appear in my C# WebBrowser.

Is there a way I can work around this and make a semi-transparent background for a C# WebBrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try something like:

```
background-color: #ff00ff;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: .5;
```

and this question might have some insights (read all the answers/comments)
[How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text)

Answer (score 1):

**Awesomium** and **Awesomium.NET** is an HTML UI Engine that supports just that.

Check the WPF `WebControl`. You can set [`WebControl.IsTransparent`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=P_Awesomium_Windows_Controls_WebControl_IsTransparent) to `true`, and load some content with say `body { background-color: transparent; }` (you can even specify a custom CSS to be applied to all loaded pages, using `WebSession`).

via Perikles C. Stephanidis