# clear text on top of blurry background

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS filters to create a blurry background and have text lay on top.  But when I try, the blurry effect is taking place on the text as well.  How can I avoid this and keep the text non-blurry?

HTML

```
<div id="intro">
   <h1 id="tagline">A dinner to remember...</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#intro{
background:url(../img/meal.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 500px;
 filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
```

}

```
#tagline {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
position: relative;
font-size: 4em;
color: #fff;
```

}

screenshot: http://d.pr/i/fAFe

Comment: It's inheriting the parents info. You need to undeclare the blur in the nested div

Comment: This question and answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text/8858972#8858972 ) deal with applying transparency to the background and keep the text opaque. Perhaps you can modify it to apply the blur to the background and keep the text sharp.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "unblur" an element within a blurred parent element. You can work around that with an absolutely positioned pseudo element, stacked behind your tagline:

```
#intro {
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

#intro:before {
    content: "";
    background:url(../img/meal.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
}

#tagline {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: #fff;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZzBX/)