# Opacity In div also opacity Content?

Tags: html, css

**Html:**:

```
<div id="Opacity"><span class="P">Here Is My P</span>
```

**Css:**

```css
#opacity {
width:400px;
height:400px;
border:black 1px solid;
opacity:0.3;
background-color:black;
}

.P {
font-family:cursive;
font-size:24px;
color:white;
}
```

but Output word are also transparent.i want word will transparent but div become transparent Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`opacity` changes the translucency of the whole element.

If you want a translucent **background**, then set the *background* to an `rgba()` colour value or use a translucent background image.

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

See [some guidance on compatibility measures](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/).

Comment: as fallback for older IE's user .class { 
       background:transparent;
       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000); 
       zoom: 1;
    } as shown [here](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text