# Change opacity of bootstrap navbar not text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, customization, navbar

How do I change the opacity of my navbar without effecting the text?

Here's how I implemented my navbar:

```
 <div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home_page">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about_page">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio_page">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact_page">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: semi-transparent background, but not text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text)

Answer (score 7):

You can add an rgba color value background to the element that you want to change the opacity of.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CUE35/)

I added this to the CSS:

```
.navbar-wrapper {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

This creates a background with opacity. You can change the color to whatever you need. Here is an rgba color reference: http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm

You can also just do a Google search for the background color value you are currently using and find the comparable rgba value.

Comment: thank you, i tried doing this but it changed the color of the container and not the menu. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add in your CSS? Then I can try to figure out a fix.