# Add opacity to background image

Tags: html, css

I have set background color and background image for a div. How can I add the opacity to background image so that the background color become visible too?

Here's my code:

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    background-color: green;
    background-image: url('http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7308/12305815623_3d1614042a_n.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 200px;    
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="wrap">Some text</div>    
</div>
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Yv6T3/

Comment: You can do it with a little work around. See this: [Transparent Background Images](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)

Comment: This has been answered gazillion times: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+background+opacity

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a partially transparent PNG is the best solution. It doesn't require any hacks, works on all platforms and degrades nicely even on IE6

Answer (score 0):

There's a several CSS properties for adding opacity:

```
opacity: 0.2; /* Standard property, for all modern browsers */
filter: alpha(opacity=20); /* For old IE */
```

Look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yv6T3/1/

Comment: Not sure this is what they are after - they only want the opacity to apply to the image, not the whole div.

Comment: Yes, this is not what I'm looking for. I only want to add opacity to the background image, not the whole div.

Answer (score 0):

have been asked already and the answer is pretty nice: [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text)

just use

```
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

where 0.5 is your transparency.

Of course, doesn't work everywhere, but for sure does in all modern browsers.