# trasparent text field but text value shows?

Tags: html, css, textfield

How could I have a transparent background in text field but I want the text inside the vale="" to show? is that possible

Here is my code
HTML

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" required class="form-control" maxlength="150" value="first name">
```

CSS

```
input[type="text"]{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color:black;
}
```

Any help please

Comment: [Seems working](http://jsbin.com/rafoj/1/edit) to me. Tested on Chrome 33

Comment: What browser support do you need?

Comment: I want the Value="first name" inside the text field to show , so everything trasparent but first name shows up

Comment: are you looking for placeholder attribute ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HahDk/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem but you can solve it by making a separate blank division and use it to put the text on. If you don't want to do that, you could create a semi transparent png image to use as background.

Link to identical question
[How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
border: none;
}
```

among other parameters. rgba() with last parameter 0.01 will make your iput completely transparent, border: none removes default border

Comment: What's the point of using `rgba()` color in this case? Whereas `transparent` value is supported in IE6 and above.

Comment: transparent did not worked for me in all browsers (maybe my fault). `rgba()` is the solution i tested and it worked for me, as i was trying to find alternative to given `transparent` solution

Comment: `rgba()` has been introduced by CSS Level 3 and it works on IE9+ However this is not the case as the OP said transparent background is working but the text is not showed up. Unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Okay I understood the question as "how can I have transparent background with ...", so maybe my fault.