# Prevent text from getting opaque when using opacity property

Tags: html, css

I just used `opacity` for `background` of content but the text in this div (I mean the content div) gets opaque as well and I cannot see the text of this `div` clearly.

I want to have the container elements `background` to be opaque but not the text.

```
div#content{
    color:white;
    width:1150px;
    background_color:black;
    opacity:.65;
    margin:0 auto;
    filter:alpha(opacity=65);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent background, but not the content (text & images) inside it, in CSS only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's `background-color` or simply `background` but not <s>`background_color`</s> and secondly, what you need is `rgba` where `a` stands for *alpha*.

So when you want to make the background color opaque, say black opaque, than use

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.65);
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LzGGN/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is less than best practice. It's ok to use `#content` rather than `div#content` as the `id` are always unique in a document.

Your `background_color:black` element is wrong. You should change that to `background-color:black;`