# CSS make the background color transparent

Tags: html, css

i wanted to make the gray bgcolor have transparency. but instead its contents became transparent instead of the bgcolor.

```
body {
   background-color: gray;
   /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `background-color` to `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)` where `red`, `green` and `blue` are between `0` and `255` and `alpha` is between `0` and `1`, with `0` being fully transparent and `1` fully opaque.

Also take a look at: [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on).

Comment: Made a quick website, we shall see: browsershots.org/http://testnaman.neocities.org/quicktest.html. EDIT: Seems to work pretty well. (The above link will only work until ~11:10pm EST 24/5/2014)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not hugely concerned with older browser compatibility then you can use the new CSS3 rgba colour definition:

`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`

This will set a transparent background colour for your element.