# How to make CSS button appear transparent

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I have the following CSS below which makes a button, but I would like to have the effect of transparency (and slightly see the background in the back). Please note that I don't wish to make it all transparent and totally invisible. Just a little bit...

I have tried messing around with the 'opacity' but that only blurs the image and distorts the color.

```
.i2Style {
  font:bold 20px"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-style:normal;
  color:#ffd324;
  background:#158edb;
  border:0px solid #4a3a00;
  text-shadow:0px -1px 1px #222222;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
  border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
  width:87px;
  padding:20px 46px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.i2Style:active {
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  top:2px;
}
```

Comment: could you provide fiddle please??

Comment: css opacity plus fallbacks for older browsers will do it

Comment: @BrettWeber that will also make OP's font in the button transparent, maybe `rgba(155,155,155,0.5)` for background color?

Comment: @SamCreamer, I think that may work better than opacity on the whole button, given the requirements

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `background` to `background-color: rgba(21,142,219,.70)`.  That will keep your button solid but make the background slightly transparent.

Answer (score 6):

Transparency is determined by the alpha channel.

For example,

```
.button{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); // red, green, blue, alpha
}
```

gives a **full black** button while,

```
.button{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); // red, green, blue, alpha
}
```

black button, with **50% transparency**.

Comment: Good answer, explanation is short and concise

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not looking for opacity, [this post outlines both methods of css opacity and transparency](http://www.dev-hq.net/html-css/20--opacity-transparency)

[For anyone looking for opacity, this link will help](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/)

For the most part, opacity is supported everywhere. It isn't REALLY necissary to privide the fallbacks, but it will help for anyone that is behind the curve on updating their browser.

If you want more information, just google css opacity, or css opacity image

Comment: As the OP mentioned, opacity will make the whole button transparent which is not what we want

Answer (score -1):

Use opacity it shouldnt distort your image.

```
.i2Style {
        opacity: 0.4;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
```