# Non-opaque text in opaque background

Tags: javascript, html, css

Spin on the popular question.  In this case, I have a div that I want to darken when I mouseover, while not darkening the text inside it.  I am halfway there; I can achieve this if I mouseover in the div anywhere besides the div that contains the text.

Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/59M7N/.  Notice that if the mouse is over the top region of the box, the hover effect will not occur.

HTML

```
<div id="text">Hello World</div>
<div id="box">
    <div id="opaque"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:5px solid black;
}

#opaque {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#opaque:hover {
    opacity:0.6;
}

#text {
    position:relative;
    color:blue;
    top:25px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent background, but not the content (text & images) inside it, in CSS only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on)

Comment: SW4's answer is the best solution, but if for whatever reason you want to retain your structure then you can use a complex selector like `#text:hover ~ #box > #opaque` and then change the opacity. (Strictly not recommended).

Comment: use `#text:hover ~ #box > #opaque{opacity:0.6;}` it works

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/59M7N/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify both your HTML and CSS by adding a transition on a background RGBA color on the `:hover`, the last value being the opacity. As you are transitioning the background only, the text is unaffected.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59M7N/1/)

`<div id="box">Hello World</div>`

CSS

```
#box {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:5px solid black;
    color:blue;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition:background 200ms ease-in;
}
#box:hover {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```