# PHP generated semi transparent background color using opacity affects text

Tags: css, opacity, rgba

I'm working with a background-color which should be 70% transparent, but I have many limitations:

1. I can't use RGBa or HSLA (I'm getting the colors from a PHP Content Management System) as Hex
2. The background color is dynamic - I can't use an image
3. when I use opacity, the text is affected as well making it unreadable.

I'm sure the only option I have is changing my PHP code to generate RGBa colors instead, but asking, do you see any other solution?

[image]

Comment: no it's not. read first limitations on my description. please READ before commenting.

Comment: Have you seen the options here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a pseudo element to the containing div. 
Like so:

```
.container:before{
 opacity:0.5;
}
```

You could also convert your hex value to RGB and then use that: [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)