# Image opacity rollover text

Tags: css, text, rollover

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/7bjxtm36/3/

I need a simple rollover where the image has a colored opacity and the text shows on rollover.

I need to use this structure where the image is in a div above the text.

This is working here but I need the text to be white.

How can I do this so the text is white.

```
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front block">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/300/" class="img-responsive"/>
                </div> 
                <div class="back block">
                   <h3>Heading</h3>
                   <h4>Sub-Heading</h4>
                   <p>Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text 
                        Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text 
                   </p>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent background, but not the content (text & images) inside it, in CSS only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7bjxtm36/5/