# how to do opacity only for background

Tags: css, background, opacity

Please tell me where is mistake. When I deleted it

```
no-repeat fixed center center / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

code exist without problems when I past it code doesnt exist.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), url("../images/image.jpg") ;
```

Comment: background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), url("../images/__surly.jpeg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: Possible dupicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on