# Will be posible at any time to animate transparency of background image?

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-animations

Let me explain you first the solutions I know.

1. I know about this: [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-to-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)
2. I know it is posible to simulate the effect using the `:after` element and animating its opacity.
3. I know that today, firefox can transition between 2 background images. (no other browser does this, as far as I know).

My question here is, is there or is planed to be in the future, a method to animate the opacity of a background image or to transition one into another. Some method that will be in a spec and that will be implemented by all browsers?

Comment: I am unsure in css but you would deffinitly have more freedom by using javascript and this would work multi browser

Comment: Yes...I believe [**Cross-fading**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#interpolating-image-combinations) is on the cards. - Also http://peter.sh/files/examples/cross-fading.html

Comment: @Paulie_D would you like to give an answer extending on this?

Comment: Not really...in fact the question is off-topic for Stack overflow. It's not been agreed as part of the CSS4 Modules spec yet (AFAIK) and the references I have found are pretty much every thing there is...apart from a bug report in FF. By all means do a Google search...now that you know the term to look for.

Comment: Hey wait i am doing this for u in js fiddle. will share now