# New to web design problems

Tags: html

I am working on a basic website and have a question. I used an image as the background and a text box to make the wording stand out, the text box I set as opaque. I wanted to add a picture to the text box but it is opaque too. How would I set the picture to be solid in an opaque text box?
Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code so we're more able to see where you're stuck and what you're doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general, a child element will take on the properties from it's parent element. You can override the parent property by giving the image it's own property. However the css opacity property has some unique properties and does not work as expected.

see this popular question for work arounds that may work for your specific problem:
[How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-to-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)