# Css background div with color layer over it

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity

Guys i have an html div and here is the code

```
<div id="mainBody"></div>
```

I gave it a background image in css and here is the code

```
#mainBody{background : url(../images/index/optimizedBackground.jpg) repeat 0 0;}
```

I want to add a color on it but this color is opacity and view the background image.

so i used this html code and adding a div inside the first one:

```
<div id="mainDiv"><div id="layoutDiv"></div></div>
```

I gave the **layout** div a background color in css:

```
#layoutDiv{
background-color : #1a1a1a;
opacity : 0.9;}
```

And it works perfectly but the problem here is anything inside the **layout** div has **0.9 opacity** and i want **layout** div only has 0.9 opacity not the divs inside it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-to-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)

Comment: assign it with a rgba colour instead. `background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0.9)` last parameter is the opacity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use an RGBA-Color. The HEX-Color `#1a1a1a` would be with an opacity of 0.9 `rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9)`

Just paste this and delete the opacity. It would be this:

```
#layoutDiv{
    background-color : rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);}
```

Comment: no problem, I just had this problem some days ago :)

Answer (score -1):

use:

background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);

Then set the text colour to what you require.

Answer (score -1):

Use RGBA, Style will apply to the particular element.

```
    #mainDiv{ background-color : rgba(22,176,33,1); }

    #layoutDiv{ background-color : rgba(233,176,288,0.5) }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j5bvhjbr/1/)