# Text inside opaque container getting fade

Tags: html, css

I have a container for which I have set the opacity to 0.6 in css. 
I have another div inside the above container where I have some text with color:white say "MY TEXT".  Now the problem is this text is getting fade as I want only the outer container to fade with opacity not the text. Can someone please help.

Below is the html code :

```
<div id='cover-part' style='text-align:center1;padding:15px'>
<div id='opaque-cover-part'>
<div id='cover-part-text'><span>THIS TEXT SHOULD NOT FADE</span></div>
</div>
```

Below is the CSS

```
#cover-part{
    position: relative;
    background: url(posts/images/1.jpg) no-repeat 0 center, linear-    gradient(white, black);
    height:250px;
    }


 #cover-part-text{
    position:relative; 
    font-size: 30px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    left: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;

    height:100px;
    width:100%;

    padding-left:15px;
    padding-top:15px; 
    }

 #opaque-cover-part{
     position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:linear-gradient(black, black);
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
     z-index:1; 
     }
```

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-to-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css?rq=1

Comment: You can move the #cover-part-text out from the #opaque-cover-part, and make it positioned absolute, over the #opaque-cover-part in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple you can just add a class or id in your span where the elements that have this class aren't opaqued.

working-example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/5jbyZv609LEaKBctKFC1?p=preview

eg:

```
.not-opaque{
      opacity:1;
    }
```

and

```
<span class='not-opaque'>THIS TEXT SHOULD NOT FADE</span>
```

Comment: this not working mate.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `opacity: 1;` to your inside container;

https://plnkr.co/edit/6o33hFTwmBoAv16alfca

Comment: try to make the backgound of the page black, to see if more clearly

Comment: my background is an image, I don't want it black

Comment: just do it for test purposes. The container more whiter makes the text more invisible.

Comment: tried. still no luck