# Why is the button looking transparent? How should I make it opaque?

Tags: html, css, button, background, background-image

The button has a background image having 0 opacity. On the top of the background image, there is a black panel with an opacity of 0.54 and the button is placed on the top of the black panel. Kindly let me know. I have spent hours to make the button opaque. Please find the image of the button here. Any kind of help will is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Login Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDK6J.png)

```
<body>
    <header class="admin-header border-blue">
        <div class="admin-background-overview">
            <div class="admin-black-panel border-yellow" align="center">
                <div class="admin-black-panel border-yellow" align="center"><!-- this is the black panel-->
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block admin-login-form-button roboto-light-font" id="admin-contact-button-id">LOG IN</button><!--this is the main button-->
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

```
    <style>
    .admin-header {
        background-image: image-url('bg.jpg');  <!-- this is the bg image-->
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;

        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-position: top;       /* The image will shift a little up if we do not insert this line*/
        background-size: 100vw 100%;
    }

    .admin-background-overview {
      /* Provides cross-browser RGBa background */
      zoom: 1;
      background: transparent;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
      //z-index: -1;
    }

    .admin-black-panel {
      width: 1392px;
      height: 374px;
      opacity: 0.54;
      margin-left: -130px;
      background-color: #000000;
    }

    .admin-login-form-button {
      /*outline: 1px solid orange;*/
      //font-family: Roboto-Light;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.4em;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #21d392;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 0 0px 0px 0;
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .admin-login-form-button:hover, .admin-login-form-button:focus {
      background-color: #21d392;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .admin-login-form-button:active {
      background-color: #21d392;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .admin-login-form-text-box:-webkit-autofill {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px black inset !important;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: in you css add
`.your-button {
   opacity: 1;
}`

Comment: Hi Ersian, unfortunately, opacity does not work for me.

Comment: @Savvy Opacity should definitely work. Apply opacity: 1.0 !important to your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the parent has an opacity of 0.54 which fades the parent **and all it's children**.

Once an opacity has been set it cannot be overridden by applying styles to the children.

```
.admin-black-panel {
  height: 374px;
  /* opacity: 0.54; */ /* remove this */
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```css
.admin-header {
  background-image: image-url('bg.jpg');
  <!-- this is the bg image--> background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  /* The image will shift a little up if we do not insert this line*/
  background-size: 100vw 100%;
}
.admin-background-overview {
  /* Provides cross-browser RGBa background */
  zoom: 1;
  background: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  //z-index: -1;

}
.admin-black-panel {
  height: 374px;
  /* opacity: 0.54; */
  background-color: #000000;
}
.admin-login-form-button {
  /*outline: 1px solid orange;*/
  //font-family: Roboto-Light;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #21d392;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 0px 0px 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.admin-login-form-button:hover,
.admin-login-form-button:focus {
  background-color: #21d392;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<header class="admin-header border-blue">
  <div class="admin-background-overview">
    <div class="admin-black-panel border-yellow" align="center">
      <div class="admin-black-panel border-yellow" align="center">
        <!-- this is the black panel-->
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block admin-login-form-button roboto-light-font" id="admin-contact-button-id">LOG IN</button>
        <!--this is the main button-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Rather than apply an opacity to the panel (unless you have specific reasons) use an [**RGBA/HSLA colo**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css?rq=1)r for your background.

Comment: Hi Paulie_D, it worked for me. Thank you very much. Appreciate your time and efforts :-)