# How to put a div above an image inside another div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I put a div with text, logo or any more stuff on the center of this banner, like the example?

```
<div class="banner">     
  <img src="img/banner2.jpg" width="100%" alt="Nasajon Sistemas">
</div>
```

**Example :**

[image]

**My Page**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)

Comment: Put Images Here

Comment: Comments around the code block are not necessary.

Comment: Make the image a background image of .baner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is an example you can fit to your needs:

```
.center{
  text-align:center;
  width:200px;   
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-100px;
  margin-top:-50px;
}

.outter{
  width:100%;
  height: 500px;;
  background-color:black;
}


<div class="outter">

  <div class="center">
    <h1>Mywebsite</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexcuria/uunwbqyb/