# Transparent menu

Tags: php, css

I tried to make the research online but couldn't find anything.
I am trying to change my menu to make it go behind my background image like on this website: https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/merchant

How can I change my css to apply it to my menu?

```
.holder{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#nav{
background:#fefefe;
padding:15px;
}

#nav .clearfix.mobile{
display: none;
}

#nav .nav-toggle{
/* margin:10px; */
display:none;
float:right;
}

#nav #nav-topmenu{
margin-top:5px;
}

#nav #nav-topmenu ul li{
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
background:url(../img/bg-nav.png) no-repeat 0 4px;
padding: 0 19px;
line-height: 17px;
margin:0;
}
#nav #nav-topmenu ul li:first-child{background:none;}
#nav #nav-topmenu ul li a{
font-size:14px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height:14px;
}

#nav #nav-topmenu-mobile ul li{
list-style:none;
padding:10px 20px;
margin:0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav #nav-topmenu-mobile ul li:first-child{background:none;}
#nav #nav-topmenu-mobile ul li a{
font-size:50px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height:50px;
/* color:#fff; */
}

#nav #nav-topmenu-mobile ul li select{
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
height: 50px;
width: 210px;
font-size: 30px;
}

#nav .popover{
min-width: 300px;
left:75% !important;
top:55px !important;
}

#nav .popover .arrow{
left:260px !important;
}

<div class="hidden-xs" id="nav-topmenu">
            <select name='langs' class="lang-selector -form-control pull-right">
                <option value="1" <?php if(LANG_ID == 1) echo "selected='selected'" ?> data-lang="en">
                    English
                </option>

                <option value="2" <?php if(LANG_ID == 2) echo "selected='selected'" ?> data-lang="fr">
                    Français
                </option>

                <option value="3" <?php if(LANG_ID == 3) echo "selected='selected'" ?> data-lang="es">
                    Espa&ntilde;ol
                </option>
            </select>
            <ul>
                <?php
                if(!Members_Factory::getRowByAuth() || Members_Factory::getRowByAuth()->is()):
                ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(), "job")?>"><?php echo __("flexible")?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php
                endif;
                ?>
                <?php
                if(!Members_Factory::getRowByAuth() || Members_Factory::getRowByAuth()->isCompany()):?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(), "find")?>"><?php echo __("Find")?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php
                endif;
                ?>
                <li>
                    <!-- <a href="https://www.example.com/blog/"><?php echo __("Blog")?></a> -->
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array("section" => "companies"), "how-it-works")?>" title="<?php echo __("How it works")?>"><?php echo __("How it works")?></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(), "pricing")?>" title="<?php echo __("Pricing")?>"><?php echo __("Pricing")?></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where on that page does the menu go "behind" the background image? And how would you see the menu if it was behind the background image?

Comment: Look at this example, that is exactly what I would like to do : https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/merchant

Comment: Yea, I did see it. I don't see anything behind their background image (nor would you if it was covered by another image). I see the menu at the top moving a div with a background down. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: I would like for my menu to take the background image. It would be transparent and we would only see the text.

Comment: i tried background-color: transparent and it was not working

Comment: They just set a background color on the header of `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)`. I just copied that from their website. In the css, that would be: `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)`.

Comment: Then make the menu have no background property so it is transparent?

Comment: The following link of a similar topic have answered here:<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css?rq=1>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your stylesheet you need to create a class or id for various pieces of the menu.

So the box the menu itself is holding in you would set an `opacity` attribute to your class or id.

Then you could use an id for the actual menu items and override their opacity with the `!important` call at the end of the attribute.

Comment: It is like that already.  I tried the opacity but it's not applying it properly

Comment: Can you drop your code in JSFiddle so I can take a look?

Comment: sorry for the delay. i only got thatmessage. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=L4tvDvDmtR

Comment: I just understood what the error is but not sure how to solve it. The change I would like to make is in my index.phtml. I have a file header.phtml that is called in layout.phtml. I would like my header to be different on my index only.

Comment: I figured what was the problem. the link for the new question is. To sum up, in my layout the header is first then I have the article. I would need to invert those for my image that is in my article to be able to go to the top. problem is, I want that change only in the index : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684838/change-header-for-index-only