# How to control the opacity of a container's background in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can i control the opacity of a picture or background color of a container or a button or a form in CSS?
Which property should use?

Comment: Using the `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5)` will apply opacity on the parent element and the child elements will not be affected. Or just `opacity: .5`

Comment: Just use [Google](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp) !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RGBA system. The A stands for Alpha which mean the opacity of the color. So let's say you want to have a transparency of 50% you have to use this code:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```