# Change opacity of background colour, but not text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the background less opaque but have the colour of the text remain the same.

```css
.overview {
  background: gray;
  width: 45%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.overview p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="overview" class="overview">
  <p>
    Blah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blah Blah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blah

  </p>
</div>
```

However both the text and background colour become dimmer

Answer (score 4):

Your [background should be an RGBA color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css), applying opacity is for the div

```
background-color:rgba(128,128,128,0.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

@wtreston 
The following code should be:

```css
.overview {
    background: gray;
    width: 45%;
    opacity: 0.3%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: large;
    border-radius: 8px;

}

.overview p {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="overview" class="overview">
        <p>
                Blah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blah
                Blah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blahBlah blah

        </p>
    </div>
```

I may have  **misunderstood** your question.

Hope This helps!