# HTML Box over Image

Tags: html, css

How do I display an element with a `background-image` that has a 35% semi-transparent layer over the element?

Note: I can get the image to appear, but not the box

CSS

```
body {background-image: url(test.jpg);}

.box-1
{
 background-color: white;
 height: 100%;
 width: 35%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box-1"></div>
```

Comment: So where are you stuck with this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css

Comment: I'm stuck at the point that my box won't show up but the background image will

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jabcreations/vhruezqc/

Comment: If the code in your question is all you have, your box will have a height of zero pixels. 100% height will only work if the parent element has a defined height. Try `100vh` to make the box the height of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I changed the height to 900 pixels and it works.