# CSS inherit previous background rgba value EXCEPT alpha (opacity)

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, opacity, rgba

I want to change only the opacity of existing background color , the color is controlled by server and i can't change it because i use a website builder , but i want to override the background opacity value with `style=""` .
I've read [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css) and also searched through internet and the only answer i found was to use `rgba(r,g,b,a)` function .

So how do i make it so that the r,g,b inherit from previous value except for the alpha (opacity) ? if not possible , any workaround to achieve the same thing ? And if pure css solution is not possible , any workaround using javascript ?

Comment: You can't. `inherit` can't be broken down and neither can color. (`rgb()` and `rgba()` are a kind of macro that generate a color setting. Once they're made, they can't be split.)

Comment: @Ouroborus ouch that's hurt , do you know any workaround ? please ?

Comment: Manually set the color as usual?

Comment: I already said i can't , the server control the color , i use a website builder , changing the color is through the builder .

Comment: Err... Do the colors provided by the tool change without your control?

Comment: @Ouroborus yes the tool allow me to change color by clicking my mouse in the web builder , but not through code , and i want the opacity to be flexible using javascript

Comment: So, yeah, if you already know what the initial color is, you can copy those numbers to the `style` attribute you want to set.

Comment: But that means the color picker in the web builder no longer work since i manually assign the value using style="" ?

Comment: The color picker will still do what it always did. And, yes, using `style` the way you intend is likely to override it if they're operating on the same element.

Comment: yes they "still work" but since i override the color picker rgba data , it means the color picker won't have any actual effect on the final result and i had to change hundreds of style="" everytime i change color @_@ that's why i'm asking this question.

Comment: are you looking for a pure css solution? Does javaScript helps?

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want to do is change how your tool's color picker works.

Comment: i have no experience on javascript , hmm ..... but my website require user to enable javascript , okay i edit my question to accept javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this in JavaScript:

1. First, target your element:

   var elem = document.querySelector('#maincontent');
2. Then, you can capture the current background-color:

   var oldColor = getComputedStyle(elem ).backgroundColor;
3. Then, update the color:

   var newColor = 'rgba' + oldColor.slice(3, -1) + ', 0.5)';

   // The above line will convert the color from rgb to rgba

   // rgb(16, 14, 23) => rgba(16, 14, 23, 0.5)
4. Now, you can update the bg-color of the target element:

   elem.style.backgroundColor = newColor;

Comment: yo this is actually clever working workaround , especially the slice part , but can you please do it without cropping string ? performance issue reason .... (upvoted anyway thanks :D)

Comment: Since you need the original `rgb` color code, you actually need to slice the string. There should be a better way to retrieve the color code, but I don't think you can do it without slicing. And, by the way, I think this small string slicing operation won't cause any performance issue

Comment: Well if it's not possible then okay , just a little more careful to optimization won't hurt . Small slicing isn't performance issue but multiply that by hundreds elements and the effect start to take place .