# opacity affects everything inside it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

React beginner here, here i'm changing the background color of rows(which works) and also giving opacity: 0.3, which gives opacity to everything to that specific row, i want to give that opacity just to background-color and not anything else.

[image]

```html
 <Table
        bordered
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={this.data}
        rowClassName={(record, index) => (record.amount > 50 ? "purple" : "green")}
      />
```

css:

```html
.purple{
background-color: rgba(190, 144, 212, 0.2) !important;
  opacity: 0.05;}

.green {
   color :green; 
}
```

data:

```js
data = [
    {
      key: 0,
      date: "2018-02-11",
      amount: 40,
      type: "income",
      note: "transfer"
    },
    {
      key: 1,
      date: "2018-03-11",
      amount: 243,
      type: "income",
      note: "transfer"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      date: "2018-04-11",
      amount: 98,
      type: "income",
      note: "transfer"
    }
    ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

`opacity` is *supposed* to effect the entire element.

If you want to lower the opacity of just the background, then make the 4th value you pass to `rgba()` smaller and don't add `opacity`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use opacity:

```
.purple{
    background-color: rgba(190, 144, 212, 0.01) !important;
}
```

Or shorter version:

```
.purple{
    background-color:#be90d403;
}
```