# How do I make my Browser Transparnt after creating the image background transparent

Tags: html, css

I have followed the link [Transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)

Which clearly show how to make the background transparent while showing an image and text on top of it.

However when I load it in my browser and output it to my Video-Mixer the page come as a white page with my text on top if it.

What I need is only the text and image to be sent to my Video-Mixer.

What I presume I need is a browser that does not give a white background,
but gives me a blank background

I have followed the example in the above page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

I looked more on the internet about transparent browsers and found this link[Electon](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window)

I would like to have other solutions if any are available