# How to make div have solid color on top of transparent background?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background: url(bg.jpg);
  margin: 0;
}

#bg {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#topbar {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="topbar"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding `opacity: 1` to the topbar div and rgba with alpha: 1.
The result: there`s an image, black background over it with opacity 0.7 and topbar which also has opacity 0.7.

My goal is to achieve darker image as a background and solid color topbar div.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a fully qualified URL to an image so that your code reproduces the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reduce the opacity of an element's background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-reduce-the-opacity-of-an-elements-background-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

`#topbar` is inside of `#bg`, so adjusting the opacity of `#bg` also affects `#topbar`. What I would do instead is omit opacity and change the background color to a transparent black.

That would look like this:

```css
body {
    background: url(bg.jpg);
    margin: 0;
}

#bg {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

#topbar {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This way only the background color is transparent instead of the entire element.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @CoffeedUpHacker is good, but here is an alternative which has some extra benefits.

Here I do not nest `#topbar` inside `#bg`; they are siblings. I then style `#bg` with the `background-image` rather than `body`. This has the following benefits:

1. You can use a `filter` to reduce the brightness instead of a partially-transparent black overlay (one element instead of two).
2. You can have the background fixed and it will work on all devices (whereas using `background-attachment: fixed` on the body element is not currently supported on mobile devices).

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
}

#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(http://picsum.photos/id/85/1500/1000);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: brightness(30%);
}

#topbar {
  margin: -1em -1em 1em -1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="topbar">top bar</div>
page text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re stuck using a non-transparent color value and that HTML structure, there is a third way to achieve the effect without overwriting the body’s background property.

```css
#bg {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

#bg::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#topbar {
    background: gray;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Note that `#topbar` must have a value set for `position` for `z-index` to work, but other values will work besides `relative`.