# Bootstrap - CSS - Copy Firefox style to IE8?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page using bootstrap v2 which works fine in Firefox, I want to apply the same css colour style in IE8 but I can't figure out how to do this:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner { 
    background-color: #1b1b1b; 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fabc75, #fa8a07); 
    /* 
    The above works in Firefox, I want to have the same work in IE8 but 
    don't know which of the below to edit
    */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#222), to(#111)); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222, #111); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #111); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222, #111); 
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    border-color: #252525; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff222222', endColorstr='#ff111111', GradientType=0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is supported:

[IE8 gradient filter not working if a background color exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508191/ie8-gradient-filter-not-working-if-a-background-color-exists)

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#fabc75', EndColorStr='#fa8a07');
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Yes, you're right it's an update. Sorry for the wrong reply. But you'll try to test in an original IE8 not in emulation mode.

Answer (score 1):

Gradient not working in IE8, you can use an image like this :

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type='text/css'>
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
        background: url('gradient.jpg') repeat-x;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

More hacks here : http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: How do I specify a solid colour?

Comment: You can add a color like this : `background: #ff0000 url('gradient.jpg') repeat-x;` or  `background-color: #ff0000;`

Comment: Actually, I found the answer, posted here.