# Getting a parent div's background image to show through

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a horizontal band on my webpage which is a div class called horizontal-strip, and I have sub-divided this into 2 separate classes called left-horizontal and right-horizontal, so I can have a list of news headlines on the left-hand half and an email signup form on the right-hand half.  The horizontal-strip div has a background image, but now that I've added the left-horizontal and right-horizontal classes, the image is not showing through.

```
.horizontal-strip {
    background: url("ColBackground.png") scroll center top repeat;
    margin: auto auto 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 950px;

}

.horizontal-strip .left-horizontal {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;

}

 .horizontal-strip .right-horizontal {
    float: right;
    width: 450px;

}
```

This is what the HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="horizontal-strip">
    <div class="left-horizontal">
        <h1>Top Stories</h1>


        <ul class="news-listing">
        <li>list of links here... </li>
        </ul>

    </div>  <!-- Closes left-horizontal div -->

    <div class="right-horizontal">

        <h1>News Sign-Up</h1>
        <p>Enter your email address below to receive automatic updates when a new story is added.</p>

        <form action="">
            Email: <input name="email" type="text">
            <input name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" type="submit">
        </form>

    </div>  <!-- Closes right-horizontal div -->
</div>  <!-- Closes horizontal-strip div-->
```

Can anyone tell me why the background image isn't showing through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not cleared the float. Add `overflow: hidden` to your `.horizontal-strip { }`. This will clear the float and make the wrapper fill to contain the contents.

Comment: No probs, glad to be of service! Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html#link3 for more info on this float clearing method.

Answer (score 0):

From "[Opacity of background, but not the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-but-not-the-text)"

```
.yourClass {
/* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
/* RGBa with 0 opacity */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */ - /* first two numbers in #00000000 define opacity */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000);
/* For IE 8 */ - /* first two numbers in #00000000 define opacity */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
}
```

I hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add another div with style clear:both after right horizontal div closes and before horizontal strip div close i.e. before last line it should fix the background.