# CSS3 Opacity inheritance

Tags: css, opacity

im trying to use Opacity to make a background semi-transparent, but any content i put in the div also takes on the semi-transparency. Anyone know how i can circle around this? Here is the code in question:

```
<div class="serviceContainer"> //The transparent div
    <div class="overflowAuto">
        <div class="left">
            <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div runat="server" id="divTitle" class="title table centreWithMargins">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div runat="server" id="divText">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.serviceContainer {width:350px; display:table; opacity:0.2; filter:alpha(opacity=20); background-image:url('../Images/glass.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;}
.serviceContainer img, p {opacity:1.0; filter:alpha(opacity=100);} //I tried to set the opacity of the contained elements, but it didnt work
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opacity of background, but not the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-but-not-the-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the image size of "../Images/glass.jpg" but the simplest and most cross-browser way probably would be to convert this image to semi-transparent png-image.

Another, not so clean and cross-browser way (not working in ie6 and ie7) would be to use :before pseudoclass.

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXDvc/

Comment: So if i save the image as semi transparent in photoshop, it will appear so in the webpage?

Comment: Yes, it will. Except in IE6 which don't have transparency for png enabled by default — it will show non-transparent png. If you want, you can enable transparency in IE6 by applying special IE filter as described here http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6 . But I'm usually just ignore it — filters are buggy, IE6 have very small market share and it's users will see background anyway, just not transparent.

Comment: Shucks. Why didn't I think of this. :) Good answer Alexey

Answer (score 2):

Don't use opacity to create transparency, use rgba(x, x, x, y) where y is the opacity level between 0 and 1:

example:

```
#something { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6); }
```

Comment: This way it wont be inherited by the child elements?

Comment: TheGateKeeper - yes, this method won't be inherited. But bear in mind that the RGBA is only for background color. If you are using background images or other effects on the parent container it will not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Opacity is inherited from the parent, so regardless of what you set for the children, they will always take on the opacity of the parent.

There are plenty of hacks and workarounds, but in general the simplest solution is to place the img / p in a separate container that is positioned (absolutely or otherwise) directly on top of the background container.

Comment: Would this still work if i dont know how big the container will actually be? I had the background image on repeat because the div is dynamically sized...