# How to set the font background with opacity but not the text inside it

Tags: html, css

I want to use background-color of the body and to apply it to the font background but with opacity 0.1

So the html is something like this

```
<font class="addFav">Add to Fav {num of all favs}</font>
```

I get the body BGcolor let say #f7f7f7  and in the  tag of the page is

```
.addFav{background-color:#f7f7f7;}
```

And in .css file i set the color to #333;

```
font.addFav{color:#333;}
```

I thought of useing two divs, but the problem is that the text inside the font is dinamic

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-but-not-the-text

Comment: I saw that but dosent work since how i said "i get the bgcolor of the body" and that color is dinamic,because the users will make there own themes so i cant set it by default

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand. You have a page background of #F7F7F7, and you want to display an element (never mind that it's `<font>`, but we'll get back to that later) with the same background color? Why not simply use a transparent background color for the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .addFav
    {
        /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000); /* For IE 8*/
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";

        opacity:0.6; /* this will work if your browser supports css3*/
    }
```

Comment: it dosent work :( , since the background color of the body is dinamic,i mean the users will make there own themes and i want to get that color to use it in the Fav font but to make it brighter

Comment: But using the exact same color won't help. If you want to make it brighter, you'll have to use Javascript to retrieve the background color, change it into something brighter and then use the result for the `<font>`. Or, use #FFFFFF with opacity, like `rgba(255,255,255,0.1)`. By the way, an opacity of 0.1 won't make much difference on #F7F7F7.

Comment: @KishoreJangid yes opacity will work but i want do color to be the same #333. With js it will be easy but i dont want to use javaScript

Comment: @MarianPetrov Kishore's example will work if you substitute his `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)` with `rgba(255,255,255,0.1)`. As I said, you will not see any difference on a background color of #F7F7F7. Use a darker one to test with!

Comment: then the only way to solve this is either use javascript or css3

Comment: use css3 `opacity:0.4;` to make it

Answer (score 2):

Hi i am mentioning the property through which you can increase and decrease the opacity of background  and that will not affect the text color its simple see the css basically you have to use the rgb color in background alpa for opacity.

background:rgba(146,146,146,0.1);

or see the example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/3/

Answer (score -1):

Just use the CSS3 opacity property.

```
.addFav{background-color:#f7f7f7;opacity:0.1;}
```

Comment: From the question: "but not the text inside it"

Comment: didnt know it affected the font aswell, then he answers his own question with "thought of useing two divs"