# Change background image opacity

Tags: html, background-image, opacity

I have a div element with text blocks and a parent div in which I have set a background image. Now I want to reduce the opacity of the background image. How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

I am looking to change the way my blog post looks at blogger.com by editing the html content. The html code looks as follows:

```
<div>
 //my blog post
</div>
```

I tried to surround the whole code above with a div element and set opacity of each div separately as below:

```
<div style="background-image:url("image.jpg"); opacity:0.5;">
<div style="opacity:1;">
 //my blog post
</div>
</div>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: use `opacity:0.5//or something`

Comment: Which browser are you testing this on?

Comment: Which browser you are testing it? and possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-but-not-the-text

Comment: You used double quotes within double quotes, try style="background-image:url('image.jpg');opacity:0.5;"

Comment: It can pose a problem once you set opacity. This then happened to me: [Set opacity of background image without affecting child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4997493/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing called background opacity. Opacity is applied to the element, its contents and all its child elements. And this behavior cannot be changed just by overriding the opacity in child elements.

Child vs parent opacity has been a long standing issue and the most common fix for it is using `rgba(r,g,b,alpha)` background colors. But in this case, since it is a background-image, that solution won't work. One solution would be to generate the image as a PNG with the required opacity in the image itself. Another solution would be to take the child div out and make it absolutely positioned.

Comment: 2021 update: It appears `rgba()` is now supported for `background`. See @Nur Nas or @Shreyas Shrawage answers.

Answer (score 96):

Nowadays, it is possible to do it simply with CSS property *"background-blend-mode"*.

```
<div id="content">Only one div needed</div>

div#content {
    background-image: url(my_image.png);
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    background-blend-mode: lighten;
    /* You may add things like width, height, background-size... */
}
```

It will blend the background-color (which is white, 0.6 opacity) into the background image. Learn more [here (W3S)](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-blend-mode.asp).

Comment: Great answer! much cleaner solution, but unfortunately does not work on IE.

Comment: @tsvikas Nothing works on IE. Honestly, I've quit considering IE while writing web pages unless it's about protecting data. :-P

Comment: @progyammer With an 8% market share, it really isn't worth the overhead required to support it any more. I'd say that Microsoft took their shot at cornering the browser market with a proprietary version and they lost. (Thank goodness.) We'll see if Edge makes any serious  inroads into Chrome's position.

Comment: @BobRodes it would be so awesome of my clients would understand this.

Comment: @Diederik On the positive side of that, the ability to deal with Microsoft's eccentricities means that you get to bill more hours. :)

Comment: @Diederik As another saying goes, money isn't everything, but it sure helps.

Comment: I know this won't work on IE/edge. But this should be the clearest and simplest solution if you don't need to consider IE/edge. Otherwise, you may need to use :before :after to handle the effects.

Comment: wow - i used `background-blend-mode:darken;` with `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6)` and it was exactly what i needed...i don't know how i missed this css property...but this is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 31):

You can't use transparency on background-images directly, but you can achieve this effect with something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4TgL/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">//my blog post</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.container {  position: relative; }

.container:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
   opacity: 0.5;
}

.content {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 2;
}​
```

Comment: I love it - thank you. The only thing is that I don't think you can programmatically change the background image - you have to hardcode it into the css files...

Comment: you have to hardcode it into the css files >> perhaps you could add it as an inline style ... style="background-image: url('image.jpg')"

Comment: is there a way to tweak this up for paralax scroll effect ?

Answer (score 23):

Try doing this:

```css
.bg_rgba {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.486);
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_rgba"></div>
```

worked in my case.
You can reduce or increase the background-color alpha value according to your needs.

Answer (score 7):

You can also simply use this:

```css
.bg_rgba {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)), url('https://picsum.photos/200');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg_rgba'></div>
```

You can change the opacity of the color to your preference.

Answer (score 4):

You can create several divs and do that:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px;">
   <div style="position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; height:100px; opacity:0.3;"><img src="urltoimage" alt=" " /></div>
   <div style="position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; height:100px;"> DIV with no opacity </div>
</div>
```

I did that couple times... Simple, yet effective...

Answer (score 0):

Responding to an earlier comment, you can change the background by variable in the "container" example if the CSS is in your php page and not in the css style sheet.

```
$bgimage = '[some image url];
background-image: url('<?php echo $bgimage; ?>');
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did is:

```
<div id="bg-image"></div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#bg-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

and you can do that by simple code:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=30);
-moz-opacity:0.3;
-khtml-opacity: 0.3;
opacity: 0.3;
```