# How to solve readability issue based on background image?

Tags: javascript, html

How to solve readability issue this link
http://web-dev1.customweather.com/sjmfx/mfakb/widget2.php?cwid=W43353&metric=true

Comment: What readability issue?

Answer (score 0):

Create a div, place the image as the background image, set a background color, change the opacity of the background image

Take a look at this for reference:
[Change background image opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605908/change-background-image-opacity)