# How to add transparency to a background image? (HTML + CSS)

Tags: html, css, tags, transparency

I have these lines In my CSS file:

```
body {
    background: url(https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/48d/woodgrain-texture-1151631.jpg);
}
```

How can I affect this image with transparency? I found a "solution" that looked like this:

```
img {
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

But I don't really know how to apply It. If I just write It down, nothing happens because I don't know how to connect It to the image I want to use.

Comment: The `img` rule would apply to an `img` tag. You've got your image as a background, so you might need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605908/change-background-image-opacity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the `rgba()` function of the `background` property and combine it with the `url()` function. The RGBA has the A for "Alpha" in addition to Red-Green-Blue, which performs just like the `opacity` property; values range from 0 to 1. The trick to using RGBA in a background image is to use two parallel `rgba()` functions inside a `linear-gradient()`. Since `rgba()` returns a color value, it can be utilized as two color stops in the linear gradient...although they technically aren't color stops, since no transition happens from two like color values. Hackish, but simple and functional.

```css
body { 
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), 
                url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/48d/woodgrain-texture-1151631.jpg')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would simply apply it as shown below;

```css
body:before { 
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url('https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg');
   opacity: 0.5;
}

.content {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="content">Hey!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

The body being your background and the content being your text and other content etc..