# Transparent HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I would like to do is create a 'div' element in an html document, and using CSS or Javascript/JQuery, change the background transparency so that it looks something like [Simple 
Calendar Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anod.calendar) or [Glass Widgets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.nicolai.buch.andersen.glasswidgets) from Android. Does anyone know a way to do this? I have tried the css Opacity function, but it messes with all the text, and if I make a second 'div' and set the transparency of that, I need to manually resize it, which I would prefer not to do.

I apologize if there is a simple way to do this, and I have wasted everyone's time, but I am really stuck on this.

Comment: You could use IE `filters` and in firefox/etc.. you can use `background: rgba(0,0,0,.2)` where .2 is the opacity (from 0-1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opacity of background, but not the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-but-not-the-text)

Comment: Easy way = use a .png image with 1x1 px size!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the alpha value in `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` if you don't want the opacity to affect the descendant text-nodes ..

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color

The only downside is no support below IE 9 (http://caniuse.com/css3-colors)

Comment: I am almost positive this doesn't work in IE. Especially older versions.

Comment: That wasn't directed towards you, sorry