# Layer one DIV over another to provide a transparent background with strong text

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is have a `div` with a transparent background that doesn't affect the text. Consider the following HTML:

```
<section class="content">
    <header>
        <h1>Description</h1>
    </header>
    Code
</section>
```

If I were to give it the following CSS:

```
background-color: #7ac0da;
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

The text would suffer from the transparency of the `section`. So, I started trying to layer the content like this:

```
<div class="code-sample">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <section class="content">
        <header>
            <h1>Description</h1>
        </header>
        Code
    </section>
</div>
```

However, with an enumerable number of iterations I'm unable to get the `section` to layer over the `div`. I'll be honest, I've tried positioning the inner `div` and `section` absolute and relative. I've tried using the `z-index`. But really, I'm just shooting in the dark here. I'd like the `.background` to have a transparent look:

```
background-color: #7ac0da;
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

but yet the `.content` then overlay that `div`. This will allow me to then float the `.code-sample` div and do like a three-column layout with those.

How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RGB color to only set the transparency for the background:

```css
.class {    
   /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
   background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
   /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
   /* For IE 8*/
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717600/1930721)

Answer (score 1):

No need for the extra background div, use RGBA values on .section to get a semi-transparent background which doesn't affect child elements

```
.content {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using RGBa sometimes gives rough edges in texts in Firefox. So it may be better in some cases to use semi-transparent png as background (may use data-uri).