# Prevent IE8 from making content transparent

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, transparency

I have a div with its individual CSS for IE8, it is transparent. How can I prevent IE8 from making content inside this div also transparent? It should be 100% visible and not transparent. Thanks so much for suggestions.

[Fiddle (to be watched at in IE8)](http://jsfiddle.net/T9LKF/show/)

```
.mybox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 362px;
    left: 0;
    width: 460px;
    height:94px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#000000;
    /* background: transparent;  */
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=60)"; 
    /* zoom:1 ; */
    /*  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";   */
    /*  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; */
    /*filter: alpha(opacity=60);*/
}
```

OT: Ok I know this is kind of old school. But still my customer wants this page to be compatible with IE8.

Related resources:

- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-color-but-not-the-text)
- [3](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/)
- [4](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/)

Answer (score 1):

Opacity in inherited to all children, by design. New browsers can use alpha-channel (RGBA) to get around this, IE8 cannot.

All you can really do is use absolute-positioning to place the content you want visible over-top of the transparent bits. You of course need to rearrange the element stacking order to do this.

You can cheat by making a copy of the contents, minus the transparent element, and placing it over top of the existing element using JS.

Answer (score 0):

If the div has the class called `.mybox` then try and definitively set the opacity perhaps by adding `opacity: 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an even better solution:

```
.mybox { 
background:none transparent scroll repeat 0 0;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#98000000,endColorStr=#98000000);
}
```

UPDATED: [Take a look with IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/T9LKF/4/show/)

I obviously messed up something with the filter declaration, I am sorry about that... :(

Comment: Ok, now it's about the markup context obviously. If you look at the **div with the class "teaserContentWrap_largeie8"**, the transparency is ok here: [Link1](http://www.nilsole.net/else/dw_mit17/mytest2.html)  - But not here: [Link2](http://www.nilsole.net/else/dw_mit17/?http://www.nilsole.net/else/dw_mit17/showcases/newtest.json&de#) ... Any ideas @Diodeus ? Thanks so much. Screenshot: [why not transparent?](http://www.nilsole.net/else/dw_mit17/why.png)

Comment: Well in the end, I took a 60% transparent black png file. Works with IE8.